# localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html does not seem to resolve.Any Ideas?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a spring boot project that is structured like below:

```
client
  build.gradle

interface
  build.gradle

service
  tests
  main
    java
    resources
 build.gradle
```

So there are three subprojects: interface,service and client.

The controllers are inside `service>main>controller` and the swagger is configured inside the `build.gradle` which is inside the service project.
When i do `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` ,i get:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/swagger-ui.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'.

I am able to get json when i hit this url:
http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs

Comment: have you included the swagger dist for the UI ?

Comment: Yes i have the dist

Answer (score 9):

I got this working,
I had a @EnableWebMVC on top of a class.Removing it fixed it.
Thanks @Sampada for your help

Comment: no probs, Please accept your own answer above so that it will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

first, add below dependencies in spring boot pom file, then add @EnableSwagger annotation on the application class and then add webappconfig class

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>




@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationWebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer 
configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
    }

}
```